# Not getting result from Cloud SQL in Android after successful query execution

Tags: java, android, mysql, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to Cloud SQL. Queries are executing successfully but I am not getting results. I created database and tables using `executeQuery()` and it executed successfully but `executeQuery()` returned `false`.

Here is my code -

```
Connection connection;
    String query = "SELECT NOW()";
    System.out.println("Connecting...");
    try {
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<IP address>/test", "root", "root");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        String result = "No Result Found";
        if (resultSet.isFirst())
            result = resultSet.getString(0);

        System.out.println("Result - " + result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("Process Terminated.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have tried to fetch data from `ResultSet` from index 0
i.e.,  `result = resultSet.getString(0);` which is not correct. 
`ResultSet's` index starts with '1' instead of zero.

> Try out with:`result = resultSet.getString(1);`

For reference: https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/database/jdbc_result_set.shtml#.Wv1PpnWFPPY

Comment: I don't think that's the case also I am getting false for executing `execute()` function but the query is executing. (`execute()` function is used for creating and inserting operations)

Comment: That's because you are using `rs.isFirst()`. Instead  use `rs.next()` which solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks @subrata it worked. But I am still not getting why my execute() is return false.

Comment: @Shubh its because `rs.isFirst()` returns `true` if the cursor points to the first row, in this case it was not, so it returned `false`.

Comment: I was talking about `execute()` Function which returns a boolean, not a `ResultSet`. (`execute()` function is used for creating and inserting operations and `executeQuery()` is used for select query). Do you have any idea about it?